# How to perform PyTorch style tensor slice update in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, slice, tensor

In Pytorch, you can easily update a tensor like so:

```
 for i in range(x_len):
     tensor_abc[:, i, i] = 0
```

How can we update a tensor like that in tensorflow?

I tried `tf.assign` and `tf.scatter_update`, but netiher work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer only pertains to variables.

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
v = tf.zeros((5,5,5))
var = tf.Variable(initial_value=v)


init = tf.variables_initializer([var])
sess.run(init)


var = var[ 1 : 2 ,
           1 : 2 ,
           1 : 2 ].assign(tf.ones((1,1,1)))

print(sess.run(var))
```

This produces

```
[[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]]
```

And this

```
var = var[ 1 : 2 ,
           0 : 1 ,
           0 : 1 ].assign(tf.ones((1,1,1)))
```

produces

```
  [[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

  ....
  ....]]
```

Another example is

```
var = var[ 1 : 2 ,
             : 2 ,
             : 2 ].assign(tf.ones((1,2,2)))

[[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
  [1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

      ....
      ....]]
```

You should explore [tf.scatter_nd](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/manip/scatter_nd) for tensors.

Answer (score -1):

[`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/variables) are the only tensors that can be updated. With variables, you would use code like `gather` and `scatter_update` for slicing.

Note that other tensors are not amenable to assignment. If this what you're trying to do, I would wonder why its necessary. However, it's still possible to create new tensors with the values you want (instead of assigning in place), with code that is a bit convoluted. For example, the following doesn't work:

```
index = ... tensor = tf.constant([0,1,2,3,4]) 
tensor[i] = 0  
## Doesn't work (TypeError: `Tensor` object does not support item assignment)
```

But either of these can do the equivalent:

```
tensor = tf.constant([0,1,2,3,4]) 
tensor = tf.concat([tensor[:i], tf.zeros_like(tensor[i:i+1]), tensor[i+1:]], 0)  
## This works, creates a new tensor
```

tensor = tf.constant([0,1,2,3,4]) 
    tensor = tf.concat([tensor[:i], tf.fill([1], 0), tensor[i+1:]], 0)  
    ## This works, creates a new tensor

Comment: Creating new tensor will work, but is it possible for multi-dimension tensor? such as update all diagonals to 0 for tensor below:  tensor = tf.Variable([
                        [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9] ],
                        [[3,2,1],[6,5,4],[9,8,7] ],
                        [[2,2,2],[2,2,2],[2,2,2] ]
                ])

Comment: If you're using variables, you can use `tf.scatter_update` instead of creating new tensors. For your specific example, what do you mean by 'all diagonals'? (which axes are you referring to?) Can you show me an example of the desired resulting matrix? That'll allow me to provide a more concrete code example